# Sinatra post redirect get, always forward to the get with the same name with post

Tags: redirect, sinatra

Here is my code:

```
post '/pathA' do
  redirect '/pathB'
end

get '/pathB' do
  do something
end

get '/pathA' do
  do something
end
```

First, if I didn't specify a redirect in postA, it will redirect to getA, I don't understand this already; Now, I want to redirect to getB, the result looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1  "POST /pathA HTTP/1.1" 303 - 0.0330
127.0.0.1  "GET /pathB HTTP/1.1" 200 15877 0.0229
127.0.0.1  "GET /pathA HTTP/1.1" 200 26017 0.0281
127.0.0.1  "GET /css/reset.css HTTP/1.1" 304 - 0.0020
......(some more resources)
```

the code in getB won't be executed. The getA page is showing. How would this happen? How can I redirect to getB?

I think the problem is I'm using ajax to send post request.

Comment: how do you redirect the page using ajax ? can you post some of that code.

Comment: @aldrien.h I was using reload function when return success, and I realized that this wouldn't redirect me anywhere. So, I changed postA to return a notifier but not a redirect to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. Change postA to return a notifier but not a redirect, and redirect from ajax code according to the notifier.
2. Post from a form.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using reload function after ajax returns success, obviously you will have the same path where you execute your ajax.

It's either you **POST** to a new  **path/url** after ajax returns success, or redirect it:

**Sample Pseudocode:**

```
$('#my_form').submit( function(event){      //or

$('#btn_submit').click( function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://my_path',
    type: 'POST', #GET
    data:  $('#my_form').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
      // redirect_to_new_path
    }
  });
});
```

Change the code the way you want function to execute.